# Load the resource bundle on start of application in boot strap in grails

Tags: java, grails, grails-2.0, resourcebundle

I created a new package under `src/java` in a Grails application for a specific resource bundle which I want to use like `src/java/resourcebundle/abc.properties`. This is working fine when I use it from other classes within `src/java`. I want to load this file when application loads. So I was trying to add it to `bootstrap.groovy` in:

```
def init = { -> def myProperties =  ResourceBundle.getBundle("src/java/resourcebundle.abc")}.
```

I am getting an exception

```
Error executing bootstraps: Can't find bundle for base name src/java/resourcebundle.abc, locale en_US
```

Any suggestions on how to load the resource bundle in bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

remove src/java? or use ClasspathResource?